# How to Apply 'mix-blend-mode: luminosity;' Effects in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, graphics

I'm working on a project that involves HTML5 Canvas, and I want to replicate the CSS 'mix-blend-mode: luminosity;' and 'backdrop-filter' effects within the Canvas. While I've already found information on applying backdrop effects to Canvas, I'm now looking for guidance on how to achieve the 'mix-blend-mode: luminosity;' filter effect as well. Can anyone provide a comprehensive explanation or code example on how to apply both of these effects to Canvas drawings or images? Your insights would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';

function draw() {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  // Draw the image onto the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // Define the coordinates and dimensions of the rectangle
  const rectX = 100; // X-coordinate of the top-left corner of the rectangle
  const rectY = 100; // Y-coordinate of the top-left corner of the rectangle
  const rectWidth = 200; // Width of the rectangle
  const rectHeight = 150; // Height of the rectangle

  // Get the pixel data of the canvas
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
  const pixels = imageData.data;

  // Apply 'mix-blend-mode: luminosity;' manually to the rectangle
  for (let i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
    // Calculate the luminance of the current pixel
    const luminance = (pixels[i] + pixels[i + 1] + pixels[i + 2]) / 3;

    // Set the RGB values of the pixel to the luminance value
    pixels[i] = luminance;
    pixels[i + 1] = luminance;
    pixels[i + 2] = luminance;
  }

  // Put the modified pixel data back onto the canvas at the same position
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, rectX, rectY);

  // Draw the rectangle with the luminance effect
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'; // Red color with 50% opacity
  ctx.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Did you do any research? There is a `globalCompositeOperation` property on the 2D canvas API.

Comment: @Kaiido, I did my research in globalCompositeOperation, but I still didn't get the way to create a mix-blend luminosity effect

Comment: Show what you tried, what you wish to accomplish and why it's not the same. SO isn't meant to do everything for you, even if you ask step by step.

Comment: @Kaiido, I updated my code with the research I did, but it still not the perfect as we can do in figma or photoshop